# Use secret_key_base as paperclip hash_secret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 declares in `config/secrets.yml` constants `secret_key_base` for "verifying the integrity of signed cookies". Theses are 128 characters (0..f) long.

Paperclip (file management) can use `:hash_secret` option to encode accessibles file names.
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Hashing

Is there a good idea to use `secret_key_base` as Paperclip hash ? It seems to be a good solution, because it is complexe enough, it's not in project's commits, and have one per environment.

Declare 2 variables in `secrets.yml` will looks like :

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 73512
  secret_key_asset: 123456

test:
  secret_key_base: 3dde2
  secret_key_asset: 789456

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  secret_key_asset: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_ASSET"] %>
```

... Seems to complicated for nothing for me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to this excerpt from the [Paperclip Wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Hashing) it would appear that secret_key_base is fine.

```
# config/initializers/paperclip_defaults.rb

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
  url: "/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension",
  hash_secret: Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
})
```

You can use a different secret key for Paperclip, but it's probably unnecessary for most projects.

Comment: It would be dangerous though since your attachment urls would stop working if you decide to modify secret_key_base, which typically would log out all users only.

Comment: @Nicolas The Paperclip wiki still has the that code on the linked page so I'm guessing it can't be that dangerous for the majority of users.  Especially if you use something like Devise for authentication there are other methods to logout all users.  If you want to update the answer to use rails credentials or some alternate methods, please go ahead.